# Bring the app to the foreground after event on react native

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native

I'm trying to bring my app to the foreground after the user hit the home button when my socket-io receives an event, after creating a bridge between my Javascript components and my java module the function works fine but my app  doesn't appear in front

this is my event (this event works fine too) :

```
const onEvent = () => {
   newRideCall.bringTheApp();
}
```

and this is my module

```
package com.taxitecdriverapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Context;
import android.app.ActivityManager;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;

import javax.annotation.Nonnull;

public class NewRideCallModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

    public static final String REACT_CLASS = "NewRideCall";
    private static ReactApplicationContext reactContext;

    public NewRideCallModule(@Nonnull ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        this.reactContext = reactContext;
    }

    @Nonnull
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return REACT_CLASS;
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void bringTheApp() {

        //I have ben try this first, not workin
        Intent i = new Intent(reactContext, MainActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        reactContext.startActivity(i);

         // and now this, both of them not working
         Context context = getReactApplicationContext();
         String pn = context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
         Intent li = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(pn);
         context.startActivity(li);

         // this Toast shows up fine
         Toast.makeText(reactContext, "TAXITEC wakeLockPhone called 0", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code. This works well for me

```
  private final ReactApplicationContext reactContext;
  public LibraryModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
    this.reactContext = reactContext;
  }

  @ReactMethod
  public void resurrectApp(){
    Intent launchIntent = reactContext.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(reactContext.getPackageName());
    if (launchIntent != null) {
      reactContext.startActivity(launchIntent);
    }
  }
```